# Xampp php_pdo_odbc not working

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

Xampp linux version: 7.1
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I already uncommented extensions=php_pdo_odbc.dll in opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

but odbc is not showing

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f75d9.jpg)

Comment: Is that extension installed?

Comment: im not sure, is it not included in XAMPP for inux?, in XAMPP windows i just uncommented it, but in linux its not working

Comment: Linux's are different. Often you have to install the PHP extensions individually and specifically

Comment: Oh and by the way, I am pretty sure that on Ubuntu a PHP Extension will not have the `.dll` extension!

Comment: can you point me on how to install it, thanks

Comment: Yes of course. **GOOGLE IT** I just did and found lots of stuff on StackExchange (ASK UBUNTU)

Answer (score 2):

you are using linux, so forget about `.dll` windows extension :

first you will need to check if you have the extension or not :

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

this will print an array with the currently installed PDO Drivers,

if you didn't get the `odbc` driver , try to enable it :

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_odbc
```

then check again, if not installed you will need to install it :

```
apt-get install php7.0-odbc
```